# Point cloud ICP alignment

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have two point clouds that I want to match. but after alignment, I get just the Input cloud, not the merged two point clouds. What could be the problem ?

I have updated my code and it still doesnt align at all

```
  pcl::PCDReader reader;
    pcl::PassThrough<pcl::PointXYZ> pass;
    pcl::NormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal> ne;
    pcl::SACSegmentationFromNormals<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal> seg;
    pcl::PCDWriter writer;
    pcl::ExtractIndices<pcl::PointXYZ> extract;
    pcl::ExtractIndices<pcl::Normal> extract_normals;
    pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr tree (new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ> ());

    // Datasets
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr input_cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud_filtered (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>),
            cloud_projected(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::Ptr cloud_normals (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>);
    pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr coefficients_plane (new pcl::ModelCoefficients), coefficients_cylinder (new pcl::ModelCoefficients);
    pcl::PointIndices::Ptr inliers_plane (new pcl::PointIndices), inliers_cylinder (new pcl::PointIndices);

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr target_cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);

    reader.read ("match.pcd", *target_cloud);
    //Read in the cloud data
    reader.read ("pointClouds_000026.pcd", *input_cloud);
    std::cerr << "PointCloud has: " << input_cloud->points.size () << " data points." << std::endl;

    //    pass.setInputCloud (input_cloud);
    //    pass.setFilterFieldName ("z");
    //    pass.setFilterLimits (-600,1400);
    //    pass.filter (*cloud_filtered);


    pcl::RadiusOutlierRemoval<pcl::PointXYZ> outrem;
    // build the filter
    outrem.setInputCloud(input_cloud);
    outrem.setRadiusSearch(50);
    outrem.setMinNeighborsInRadius (5);
    // apply filter
    outrem.filter (*cloud_filtered);

    std::cerr << "PointCloud after filtering has: " << cloud_filtered->points.size () << " data points." << std::endl;
    writer.write ("table_scene_mug_stereo_textured_filtered.pcd", *cloud_filtered, false);

    // Estimate point normals
    ne.setSearchMethod (tree);
    ne.setInputCloud (cloud_filtered);
    ne.setKSearch (50);
    ne.compute (*cloud_normals);

    // Create the segmentation object for the planar model and  set all the parameters
    seg.setOptimizeCoefficients (true);
    seg.setModelType (pcl::SACMODEL_NORMAL_PLANE);
    seg.setNormalDistanceWeight (0.1);
    seg.setMethodType (pcl::SAC_RANSAC);
    seg.setMaxIterations (1000);
    seg.setDistanceThreshold (0.09);
    seg.setInputCloud (cloud_filtered);
    seg.setInputNormals (cloud_normals);
    seg.setEpsAngle(0.05320);
    Eigen::Vector3f YAxis(0,1,0);
    seg.setAxis(YAxis);
    // Obtain the plane inliers and coefficients
    seg.segment (*inliers_plane, *coefficients_plane);
    std::cerr << "Plane coefficients: " << *coefficients_plane << std::endl;

    // Extract the planar inliers from the input cloud
    extract.setInputCloud (cloud_filtered);
    extract.setIndices (inliers_plane);
    extract.setNegative (false);



    // Write the planar inliers to disk
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud_plane (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> ());
    extract.filter (*cloud_plane);
    std::cerr << "PointCloud representing the planar component: " << cloud_plane->points.size () << " data points." << std::endl;
    writer.write ("cloudplane.pcd", *cloud_plane, false);

    pcl::ProjectInliers<pcl::PointXYZ> proj;
    proj.setModelType (pcl::SACMODEL_PLANE);
    proj.setIndices (inliers_plane);
    proj.setInputCloud(cloud_filtered);
    proj.setModelCoefficients (coefficients_plane);
    proj.filter (*cloud_projected);
    std::cerr << "PointCloud after projection has: "
              << cloud_projected->points.size () << " data points." << std::endl;

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud_hull (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
    pcl::ConvexHull<pcl::PointXYZ> chull;
    chull.setInputCloud (cloud_projected);
    chull.setComputeAreaVolume(true);
    chull.reconstruct (*cloud_hull);

    std::cerr <<"area of convex hull: "<< chull.getTotalArea()<<std::endl;
    std::cerr << "Convex hull has: " << cloud_hull->points.size () << " data points." << std::endl;

    writer.write ("table_scene_mug_stereo_textured_hull.pcd", *cloud_hull, false);

    pcl::IterativeClosestPoint<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointXYZ> icp;

    icp.setInputSource (cloud_plane);
    icp.setInputTarget (target_cloud);
    icp.setEuclideanFitnessEpsilon(0.000000000001);
    icp.setTransformationEpsilon(0.0000001);
    icp.setMaximumIterations(10000);
    icp.setMaxCorrespondenceDistance(300);
    writer.write("nonal_igned.pcd", *cloud_plane + *target_cloud, false);

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> final;

    icp.align (final);
    pcl::transformPointCloud(*cloud_plane, *cloud_plane, icp.getFinalTransformation());

    final = final + *target_cloud;

    writer.write("aligned.pcd", final, false);
    std::cout << "has converged:" << icp.hasConverged() << " score: " << icp.getFitnessScore() << std::endl;
    std::cout << icp.getFinalTransformation() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

ICP uses the input_cloud with its viewpoint as reference. It tries to align the target_cloud such that the distance between the correspondences points is iteratively minimized. The finial transformation of this will be used by

```
icp.align(Final);
```

To algin the target_cloud and stores it in `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> Final`.

To merge both point clouds after ICP, you have to transform both into the same viewpoint like this

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> transformed_target_cloud;
Eigen::Matrix4f transformation_matrix = icp.getFinalTransformation();
pcl::transformPointCloud(Final, transformed_target_cloud, transformation_matrix);

pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> transformed_input_cloud;
Eigen::Isometry3f pose(Eigen::Isometry3f(Eigen::Translation3f(
                      input_cloud.sensor_origin_[0],
                      input_cloud.sensor_origin_[1], 
                      input_cloud.sensor_origin_[2])) * 
                      Eigen::Isometry3f(input_cloud.sensor_orientation_));
transformation_matrix = pose.matrix();
pcl::transformPointCloud(input_cloud, transformed_input_cloud, transformation_matrix);

// now both point clouds are transformed to the origin and can be added up
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> output_cloud;
output_cloud += transformed_input_cloud;
output_cloud += transformed_target_cloud;
```

Comment: its still not aligned I dont know what Im doing wrong. I have updated the code in the post take a look please

Comment: Can you share both initial point clouds as *.PCD file somehow? So I can try it. Maybe ICP does not converge to an optimal transformation. Your setup with MaximumIterations of 1000 and MaxCorrespondenceDistance of 200 seems too big.

Comment: here is the first point cloud http://www.mediafire.com/download/4a8p97zv712c5cu/pointClouds_000023%282%29.pcd
here is the second point cloud http://www.mediafire.com/download/sahhwnx5ws8rp22/matched.pcd

please look at the updated code, Im trying to extract a plane and then do the matching against a plane using icp

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Comment: Ok, these two point clouds are too different. Therefore, an ICP can not find enough correspondences.

Comment: how to segmenet the horizontal plane out of the cloud

Comment: Have you looked into this example? http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/planar_segmentation.php. But I think this has nothing to do with the initial question!

Comment: I will add two point clouds and try to align them because its not working at all

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/download/41lewzq7tcql114/cloudplane.pcd
http://www.mediafire.com/download/8no7heel08ena9y/pointClouds_000034.pcd
Thanks alot

Comment: can you help me please. I dont know why they are not aligned

Comment: did you test the two clouds please ?

Comment: can you please test them, I really need it, and thanks for your efforts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116209/discussion-between-andre-and-bashbug).

Comment: did you try to align them, its impossible, i tried a lot but they cant be aligned

Comment: what parameters that you choosed